# Does the optimum solution of a TSP remain the optimum even after skipping a few cities?

Tags: traveling-salesman

Let's say that I know the global optimum solution to a 100-city standard Travelling Salesman Problem. Now, lets say that the salesman wants to skip over 5 of the cities. Does the TSP have to be re-solved? Will the sequence of cities obtained by simply deleting those cities from the previous optimum solution be global optimum for the new 95-city TSP?

Answer (score 2):

**Updated:** Replaced counterexample with Euclidean instance.

Great question.

No, if you remove some cities, the original sequence of cities does **not** remain optimal. Here is a counterexample:

[image]

The node coordinates are:

```
0 0
4 0
4 2
2.6 3
10 3
4 4
4 6
0 6
```

Here is the optimal tour:

[image]

Now suppose we don't need to visit node 5. If we just "close up" the original tour, the resulting tour has a cost of 21.94:

[image]

But the optimal tour has a cost of 21.44:

[image]

(If you want to remove 5 cities instead of 1, just put all 5 cities close together all the way on the right.)

Comment: By "standard" TSP, I was referring to the a TSP were the cost functions is the sum of Euclidean distances between the cities. Your example uses a variant of TSP with specified costs.

Comment: @Prometheus Does my revised solution address your comment? If so, please consider accepting my solution.

Comment: This is a relatively old topic, but i have a follow up question: Does anyone know how to easily impose a good lower bound on the solution for the reduced problem? The only thing i came up with is to substract the lengths of both edges of the node that is being removed but this can get "arbitrarily weak", i'm almost sure there should exist a way to push the bound further up tho without any costly computation. Any ideas?